# Как работает Key в Php

Tags: php

Не могу понять как работают ключи, в php. Вот пример из туториола, зачем тут столько слов "массив"?

array_keys ( array $array ) : array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы состоят из двух составляющих:

- Ключ
- Значение

Можно представить массив, например, как десять коробок, расположенных в ряд.

Чтобы узнать, что находится в той или иной коробке, Вам необходимо указать, в какую именно коробку Вы хотите посмотреть: третью, пятую, восьмую. Номер коробки по порядку – это и есть ключ. А то, что лежит в коробке, это – значение.

```
$boxes = Array(
  0 => 'Apple',
  1 => 'Pinaple',
  2 => 'Orange',
  3 => 'Cucumber',
  4 => 'Tomato'
)
```

Коробка №0 – яблоко, коробка №2 - апельсин, коробка №4 - томат.

В таких массивах обращение к элементу происходит с помощью указания числового ключа:

```
echo $boxes[0]; // выведет "Apple"
echo $boxes[3]; // выведет "Cucumber"
```

Однако, иногда бывают ситуации, когда невозможно сказать номер коробки по порядку (например, они стоят кучками, друг на друге). В таком случае, можно указать на форму или цвет коробки. Это называется ассоциативными массивами.

```
$boxes = Array(
  'green_box' => 'Apple',
  'yellow_box' => 'Pinaple',
  'orange_box' => 'Orange',
  'darkgreen_box' => 'Cucumber',
  'red_box' => 'Tomato'
)
```

В таком случае, в качестве ключа служит, так скажем, описания коробок: зелёная, желтая, оранжевая, тёмно-зелёная, красная.

```
echo $boxes['yellow_box']; // выведет "Pinaple"
echo $boxes['red_box']; // выведет "Tomato"
```

array_keys() – функция, возвращающая массив со всеми ключами передаваемого массива. Для примера, возьмите массив выше, с цветными коробками. При применении этой функции, вернётся массив:

```
print_r(array_keys($boxes));
```

Выведет следующее:

```
Array(
  'green_box',
  'yellow_box',
  'orange_box',
  'darkgreen_box',
  'red_box'
)
```

То есть вернутся только описания коробок, без указания того, что у них внутри.

Answer (score 2):

array_keys - название функции, которая принимает аргумент.
Аргумент - переменную назвали в примере $array, хотя могли назвать как угодно, и вы не поверите, но переменная типа массив, поэтому перед именем переменной тоже стоит слово array как тип данных этой переменной.
После скобок и двоеточия снова указан тип данных array - то есть функция возвращает не просто ключи. Она возвращает массив ключей.

Answer (score 0):

> зачем тут столько слов "массив"?

К массивам эти слова не имеют отношения. Таким образом указывается **тип аргумента** и **возвращаемого значения**.

```
array_keys ( array $array ) : array
```

означает, что аргументом функции может быть только массив, и вернуть она может только массив, иначе будет ошибка.

У строковых функций тип, соответственно, будет строка:

```
trim ( string $str ) : string
```

означает, что аргументом функции может быть только строка, и вернуть она может только строку, иначе будет ошибка.